# Como adicionar uma nova coluna com a média do grupo em pandas?

Tags: pandas

Estou tentando inserir uma nova coluna com a média de gols em casa por equipe .

Calculei a média , porém não consigo inserir esse valor em uma nova coluna.

base de dados: https://www.football-data.co.uk/brazil.php[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código:

```
dataset = dataset.drop ('League', axis = 1)
dataset = dataset.drop ('Country', axis = 1)
dataset = dataset.drop ('Time', axis = 1)
display(dataset)

dataset = dataset.drop ('Date', axis = 1)
dataset.columns = ["Temporada","Home","Away","Gols Casa", "Gols Fora", "Resultado", "Odds Casa","Odds Empate","Odds Fora"]

dataset.head()
```

```py
Media_GolsCasa = dataset[['Home','Gols Casa']].groupby('Home').mean()
Media_GolsCasa
```

Comment: você pode disponibilizar o banco de dados? Apenas com a descrição está difícil entender o problema. Considere também substituir a imagem por uma tabela formatada em markdown

Comment: Valeu pela dica , inserir o banco para ficar mais fácil a compreensão .

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 2):

Importando o pandas

```
import pandas as pd
```

Lendo o dataset

```
dataset = pd.read_excel('./BRA.xlsx')
```

Removendo colunas desnecessárias

```
dataset.drop(columns=['League','Country','Time','Date'], inplace=True)
```

Renomeando colunas

```
dataset.columns = ["Temporada","Home","Away","Gols Casa", "Gols Fora", 
                   "Resultado", "Odds Casa","Odds Empate","Odds Fora",
                  'MaxH','MaxD','MaxA','AvgH','AvgD','AvgA']
```

Agrupando para calcular a média

```
Media_GolsCasa = dataset[['Home','Gols Casa']].groupby('Home').mean()
Media_GolsCasa.rename(columns={'Gols Casa':'Média gols Casa'}, inplace=True)
```

Juntando um data frame com o outro

```
dataset.join(Media_GolsCasa, on='Home')
```

Saída

```
|     | Temporada | Home           | Away           | Gols Casa | Gols Fora | Resultado | Odds Casa | Odds Empate | Odds Fora | MaxH | MaxD | MaxA  | AvgH | AvgD | AvgA  | Média gols Casa    |
|-----|-----------|----------------|----------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-------------|-----------|------|------|-------|------|------|-------|--------------------|
| 0   | 2012      | Palmeiras      | Portuguesa     | 1.0       | 1.0       | D         | 1.75      | 3.86        | 5.25      | 1.76 | 3.87 | 5.31  | 1.69 | 3.5  | 4.9   | 1.7133333333333334 |
| 1   | 2012      | Sport Recife   | Flamengo RJ    | 1.0       | 1.0       | D         | 2.83      | 3.39        | 2.68      | 2.83 | 3.42 | 2.7   | 2.59 | 3.23 | 2.58  | 1.3282442748091603 |
| 2   | 2012      | Figueirense    | Nautico        | 2.0       | 1.0       | H         | 1.6       | 4.04        | 6.72      | 1.67 | 4.05 | 7.22  | 1.59 | 3.67 | 5.64  | 1.131578947368421  |
| 3   | 2012      | Botafogo RJ    | Sao Paulo      | 4.0       | 2.0       | H         | 2.49      | 3.35        | 3.15      | 2.49 | 3.39 | 3.15  | 2.35 | 3.26 | 2.84  | 1.3377483443708609 |
| 4   | 2012      | Corinthians    | Fluminense     | 0.0       | 1.0       | A         | 1.96      | 3.53        | 4.41      | 1.96 | 3.53 | 4.41  | 1.89 | 3.33 | 3.89  | 1.488235294117647  |
| 5   | 2012      | Internacional  | Coritiba       | 2.0       | 0.0       | H         | 1.76      | 3.63        | 5.66      | 1.77 | 3.9  | 6.0   | 1.66 | 3.55 | 5.1   | 1.576158940397351  |
| 6   | 2012      | Ponte Preta    | Atletico-MG    | 0.0       | 1.0       | A         | 3.12      | 3.45        | 2.44      | 3.12 | 3.45 | 2.62  | 2.74 | 3.23 | 2.45  | 1.2842105263157895 |

...
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma alternativa à solução do lmonferrari é usar o método `transform`:

```py
dataset['Media_GolsCasa']=dataset.groupby("Home")["Gols Casa"].transform("mean")
```

Comment: Muito boa a solução!