# Criar coluna Média Móvel para varios ativos (python - finanças)

Tags: python

gostaria se saber como fazer a coluna de média ao lado de cada empresa da lista

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

empresas1 = ['USIM5.SA','ITSA4.SA','PETR4.SA','WEGE3.SA','BBAS3.SA']
# historico de volume das empresas em colunas
hist_vol = yf.download(empresas1, period='5y')['Volume']

# definindo as coluna das médias
periodo1 = 20

# saida (resultado)
hist_vol
```

Resultado atual sem tratamento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado esperado para a saída dos resultados após adição das colunas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como adicionar uma nova coluna com a média do grupo em pandas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/494909/como-adicionar-uma-nova-coluna-com-a-m%c3%a9dia-do-grupo-em-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou sugerir uma abordagem um pouco diferente; ao invés de partir de um dataframe onde cada coluna representa uma empresa, vamos trabalhar com um dataframe onde cada coluna representa um **atributo** do seu dado, e cada linha representa uma **instância** dele (nesse caso, podemos pensar na instância como sendo o estado da empresa em um dado ponto do tempo).

Esse tipo de formatação de dados é chamada de **dados limpos** ou **organizados** (do inglês *tidy data*), e facilita muito a nossa vida quando queremos realizar operações dentro de determinados grupos (no seu caso, cálculo da média móvel para cada empresa). Inclusive muitas bibliotecas de Python já estão prontas para trabalhar com dados limpos de forma bastante simples.

**Primeiro passo** - limpando os dados:

```
data = hist_vol.reset_index().melt(id_vars=['Date'], var_name='Company', value_name='Volume')
print(data)

#            Date   Company      Volume
# 0    2016-08-26  BBAS3.SA   8260600.0
# 1    2016-08-29  BBAS3.SA   8798800.0
# 2    2016-08-30  BBAS3.SA   8116800.0
# 3    2016-08-31  BBAS3.SA  18848500.0
# 4    2016-09-01  BBAS3.SA   8984100.0
# ...         ...       ...         ...
# 6200 2021-08-20  WEGE3.SA   9713000.0
# 6201 2021-08-23  WEGE3.SA   6477600.0
# 6202 2021-08-24  WEGE3.SA   7439700.0
# 6203 2021-08-25  WEGE3.SA   7436300.0
# 6204 2021-08-26  WEGE3.SA   1345200.0
# 
# [6205 rows x 3 columns]
```

Viu como ficou mais simples? Cada coluna representa o volume de uma dada empresa em um dado ponto do tempo.

Aqui aplicamos dois métodos sobre o dataframe: `reset_index` serve para tirar a data do índice do dataframe e transformá-la em uma coluna padrão. Já `melt` serve justamente para consolidar dados espalhados em diversas colunas - dá para pensar como sendo o oposto de pivotar uma tabela.

**Segundo passo** - calculando a média móvel:

```
periodo = 20
data['Mean_Volume'] = data.groupby('Company')['Volume'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(periodo).mean())
print(data)

#            Date   Company      Volume  Mean_Volume
# 0    2016-08-26  BBAS3.SA   8260600.0          NaN
# 1    2016-08-29  BBAS3.SA   8798800.0          NaN
# 2    2016-08-30  BBAS3.SA   8116800.0          NaN
# 3    2016-08-31  BBAS3.SA  18848500.0          NaN
# 4    2016-09-01  BBAS3.SA   8984100.0          NaN
# ...         ...       ...         ...          ...
# 6200 2021-08-20  WEGE3.SA   9713000.0    8973000.0
# 6201 2021-08-23  WEGE3.SA   6477600.0    9101260.0
# 6202 2021-08-24  WEGE3.SA   7439700.0    9136580.0
# 6203 2021-08-25  WEGE3.SA   7436300.0    8076375.0
# 6204 2021-08-26  WEGE3.SA   1345200.0    7556780.0
# 
# [6205 rows x 4 columns]
```

Aqui, utilizamos `groupby` para agrupar os dados por cada empresa, e em seguida `transform`, que aceita uma função qualquer, aplica a cada grupo e em seguida devolve uma coluna de mesmo tamanho dos dados não-agrupados (em resumo, isso serve para criarmos uma nova coluna nos dados não-agrupados, mas cujos valores foram calculados para cada grupo). E a função que passamos para `transform` é justamente uma média móvel de janela = `periodo`.

Como esperado, a média móvel dos volumes nos primeiros pontos de tempo foram `NaN`s, porque ela só é calculada a partir do momento em que há um número de pontos >= `periodo` (a forma de calcular da média móvel pode ser configurada - veja a documentação de `DataFrame.rolling` [aqui](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)).

**Demonstração** - seus dados já estão agrupados, agora basta utilizá-los. Por exemplo, você pode obter a média móvel de uma dada empresa com:

```
empresa_de_interesse = 'BBAS3.SA'
valores = data.loc[data['Company'] == empresa_de_interesse]['Mean_Volume']
print(valores)

# 0              NaN
# 1              NaN
# 2              NaN
# 3              NaN
# 4              NaN
#            ...    
# 1236    13849830.0
# 1237    14491865.0
# 1238    14894930.0
# 1239    14850910.0
# 1240    14518300.0
# Name: Mean_Volume, Length: 1241, dtype: float64
```

A biblioteca `seaborn` funciona muito bem para plotar **dados organizados em dataframes limpos**:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.lineplot(data=data,  x='Date', y='Mean_Volume', hue='Company')
plt.show()
```

Nesse caso, o argumento `hue='Company'` faz com que o seaborn separe a plotagem de cada empresa em linhas de cores diferentes automaticamente.

Gráfico gerado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]